# PHP+Ubuntu Send email using gmail form localhost

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, localhost, postfix-mta

I have searched several posts on this but no luck. Everyone is using postfix. But when I gone through the text on 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

> What is a Mail Transfer Agent
>   In other words, it's a mail server not a
>   mail client like Thunderbird, Evolution, Outlook, Eudora, or a
>   web-based email service like Yahoo, GMail, Hotmail, Earthlink,
>   Comcast, SBCGlobal.net, ATT.net etc.... If you worked for a company
>   named Acme and owned acme.com, you could provide your employees with
>   email addresses @acme.com. Employees could send and receive email
>   through your computer, but not without your computer running all the
>   time. **If all your email addresses are at a domain (@gmail.com,
>   @yahoo.com) you do not own (you don't own Google) or do not host
>   (acme.com) then you do not need this at all.**

As the last line says You cannot us it for gmail or yahoo to make it work from localhost..!

Can anyone tell me how can I configure mail server on localhost using gmail SMTP? I am using Ubuntu 14.

Links I have tried before NONE of them worked for me. No error or warnings during testing of below listed links

https://askubuntu.com/questions/314664/sending-php-mail-from-localhost
https://askubuntu.com/questions/228938/how-can-i-configure-postfix-to-send-all-email-through-my-gmail-account
https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/
https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mail/postfix-debugging/

Answer (score 29):

Please do following steps to send mail from *localhost* on **Ubuntu/Linux** through **gmail** :-

For that you need to install **`msmtp`** on Linux/Ubuntu server.

Gmail uses ***https://*** (it's hyper text secure) so you need install `ca-certificates`

```
~$ sudo apt-get install msmtp ca-certificates
```

It will take few seconds to install `msmtp` package.

Now you have to create configuration file(**`msmtprc`**) using , gedit editor.

```
~$ sudo gedit /etc/msmtprc
```

Now you have to copy and paste following code in gedit (*file you created with above command*)

```
defaults
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
auth on
user MY_GMAIL_ID@gmail.com
password MY_GMAIL_PASSSWORD
from MY_GMAIL_ID@gmail.com
logfile /var/log/msmtp.log
```

Don't forget to replace **MY_GMAIL_ID** with your "*gmail id*" and **MY_GMAIL_PASSSWORD** with your "*gmail password*" in above lines of code.

Now create `msmtp.log` as

```
~$ sudo touch /var/log/msmtp.log
```

You have to make this file readable by anyone with

```
~$ sudo chmod 0644 /etc/msmtprc
```

Now Enable sendmail log file as writable with

```
~$ sudo chmod 0777 /var/log/msmtp.log
```

Your configuration for gmail's SMTP is now ready. Now send one test email as

```
~$ echo -e "Subject: Test Mail\r\n\r\nThis is my first test email." |msmtp --debug --from=default -t MY_GMAIL_ID@gmail.com
```

Please check your Gmail inbox.

---

Now if you want to send email with php from localhost please follow below instructions:-

Open and edit *`php.ini`* file

```
~$ sudo gedit /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

You have to set ***sendmail_path*** in your *`php.ini`* file.

Check your SMTP path with

```
~$ which msmtp
```

and you will get `/usr/bin/msmtp` like that.

Search `sendmail_path` in *`php.ini`* and edit as below

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/msmtp -t
```

Please check 3rd line carefully there is no semicolon before `sendmail_path`.

Now save and exit from gedit. Now it's time to restart your *`apache`*

```
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now create one php file with mail function from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

Do test and enjoy !!

Comment: If you are setting this up for your own domain, that's using gmail for emails, you have to enable acces from "less secure apps". Log in to your admin.google.com, in security enable users to manage their less secure app settings. In accounts.google.com for the user you want to send emails from, enable less secure apps.