# Gmail is blocking to send email via SMTP?

Tags: email, ssl, gmail, msmtp

I have tried to set up `msmtp` server from this question [PHP+Ubuntu Send email using gmail form localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969783/phpubuntu-send-email-using-gmail-form-localhost/45125490#45125490). So I have set the `default` (account) to send from:

*/etc/msmtprc*:

```
defaults
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
auth on
user autak987@gmail.com
password PASSWORD #not real password
from autak987@gmail.com
logfile /var/log/msmtp.log
```

And now when I try to send a test email (executed as root):

```
echo -e "Subject: Test Mail\r\n\r\nThis is my first test email." | msmtp --debug --from=default -t autak987@gmail.com
```

gives:

```
loaded system configuration file /etc/msmtprc
ignoring user configuration file /root/.msmtprc: No such file or directory
falling back to default account
using account default from /etc/msmtprc
host = smtp.gmail.com
port = 587
source ip = (not set)
proxy host = (not set)
proxy port = 0
timeout = off
protocol = smtp
domain = localhost
auth = choose
user = autak987@gmail.com
password = *
passwordeval = (not set)
ntlmdomain = (not set)
tls = on
tls_starttls = on
tls_trust_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
tls_crl_file = (not set)
tls_fingerprint = (not set)
tls_key_file = (not set)
tls_cert_file = (not set)
tls_certcheck = on
tls_min_dh_prime_bits = (not set)
tls_priorities = (not set)
auto_from = off
maildomain = (not set)
from = default
add_missing_from_header = on
add_missing_date_header = on
remove_bcc_headers = on
dsn_notify = (not set)
dsn_return = (not set)
logfile = /var/log/msmtp.log
logfile_time_format = (not set)
syslog = (not set)
aliases = (not set)
reading recipients from the command line and the mail
<-- 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o60sm9122564eda.30 - gsmtp
--> EHLO localhost
<-- 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2a00:1028:8d1b:f32a:baac:e4e8:de4:df3c]
<-- 250-SIZE 35882577
<-- 250-8BITMIME
<-- 250-STARTTLS
<-- 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-- 250-PIPELINING
<-- 250-CHUNKING
<-- 250 SMTPUTF8
--> STARTTLS
<-- 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
TLS session parameters:
    (TLS1.3)-(ECDHE-X25519)-(ECDSA-SECP256R1-SHA256)-(AES-256-GCM)
TLS certificate information:
    Owner:
        Common Name: smtp.gmail.com
        Organization: Google LLC
        Locality: Mountain View
        State or Province: California
        Country: US
    Issuer:
        Common Name: GTS CA 1O1
        Organization: Google Trust Services
        Country: US
    Validity:
        Activation time: Tue 11 Aug 2020 10:57:38 AM CEST
        Expiration time: Tue 03 Nov 2020 09:57:38 AM CET
    Fingerprints:
        SHA256: 8A:D6:DC:62:1D:6B:BB:B9:45:03:38:E8:40:AC:8C:A8:60:75:CF:B6:95:93:83:4C:ED:AD:BA:CA:71:47:44:E7
        SHA1 (deprecated): 84:5D:7F:E9:0E:7C:6A:C0:70:F6:04:09:4A:1C:AA:5D:6C:BF:11:E2
--> EHLO localhost
<-- 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2a00:1028:8d1b:f32a:baac:e4e8:de4:df3c]
<-- 250-SIZE 35882577
<-- 250-8BITMIME
<-- 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
<-- 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-- 250-PIPELINING
<-- 250-CHUNKING
<-- 250 SMTPUTF8
--> AUTH PLAIN AGF1dGFrOTg3QGdtYWlsLmNvbQBNaWxhbmJhcm9zMTIz
<-- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
<-- 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o60sm9122564eda.30 - gsmtp
msmtp: authentication failed (method PLAIN)
msmtp: server message: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
msmtp: server message: 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o60sm9122564eda.30 - gsmtp
msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)
msmtp: cannot log to /var/log/msmtp.log: cannot open: Permission denied
msmtp: log info was: host=smtp.gmail.com tls=on auth=on user=autak987@gmail.com from=default recipients=autak987@gmail.com smtpstatus=535 smtpmsg='535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o60sm9122564eda.30 - gsmtp' errormsg='authentication failed (method PLAIN)' exitcode=EX_NOPERM
```

So the log says `<-- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at`, but I got an warning email `someone has tried to log in your account` Which I confirm was me. Then it says `The application you have tried to use, Google blocked, because it does not fulfil our security standards`. So the `msmtp` does not fulfil security standard? I have donwloaded all the certificate needed (and credentials were correct either login or password). So if `msmtp` does not fulfil security standard, how can I send email from php form?

Comment: Did you try enabling Access for less secure apps

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enable Less Secure Apps in your google account to allow the use of smtp
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

If you use 2 factor authentication you will need to generate an app specific password
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en